# org.json.JSONException: Value [] of type org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject

Tags: android

i have a running app but i had a little problem with my sever,i have yet to solve my server problems and i'm encountering this problem with my log in the error comes from the authentication method.the error says jsonarray cannot be converted to jsonobject i've made a pastbin of my log and i was hoping someone can take a look at it and tell what my problem is.i think my problem is that i cant access my database but im not really sure if its the problem or my problem is my json.i cant hink of way to authenticate my username and password withour having problem like "at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:111)" here is my paste bin http://pastebin.com/zgzbxcSV

Comment: what json string are you getting in response?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you get from the server a (maybe empty) json array and you are try to convert it in a JsonObject.

instead of

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(string);
```

you should do

```
JSONArray obj = new JSONArray(string);
```

Comment: the problem is with my log in activity.i was thinking it has something to do with my connection to the server?do you think i need to make another API because my code is working perfectly until i had a problem with my server.or i should reprogram my log in activity suggestion will be appreciated thank you

Comment: I will go with an AsyncTask, HttpUrlConnection and the android json library. It is a simply task to perform. Also check if something server side has changed

Comment: i tried doing it with JSONArray but then i get error in "pref_editor.putString("Name", result.getString("name"));"
i need to make it an object right how can i make it in JSONArray?

Comment: What error did you get? Can you post the response of the server?

Comment: no error i put the logcat did you check it?i cant log in that is the server's response i think i cant get into the servers data base?coz i know my username and password is correct but i cant log in

Comment: Hello , how can i make as generic as every time direct array will not be there?

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to convert **JsonObject** to **JsonArray** so getting error.

You have to convert proper `jsonObject to another object` as per your requirement.

You can find useful [demo](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/) with explanation.

If you find and trouble for parsing your json after researching this demo then let me know.